# C# example of Parcelable class with property List<Object>

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, parcelable

Can someone please provide a simple C# example of passing an object through Intent using Parcelable method, where the object contains a List of another object?  I really just need to figure out how to write/read the list.  I have tested some code that successfully passed through OtherObject so that should be properly set up for Parcelable, same with the code within FromActivity and ToActivity. Here is some sample code of what I am looking for:

```
Public Class MyObject : Object, IParcelable
{
    public int myId {get; private set;}
    public List<OtherObject> myObjectList {get; set;}

    public MyObject(int myId)
    {
        //This constructor called on the item being passed through intent
        this.myId = myId;
        RepoClass _repoClass = new RepoClass();
        this.myObjectList = _repoClass.BuildList(myId).ToList();
    }

    public MyObject(Parcel parcel)    //Passed from Creator object
    {
        this.myId = parcel.ReadInt();
        this.myObjectList = new List<OtherObject>

        //NOT SURE HOW TO READ -- tried the following:
        //parcel.ReadList(myObjectList, new OtherObject().Class.ClassLoader);        //Not Working
        //parcel.ReadTypedList(myObjectList, new OtherObjectParcelableCreator();     //Not Working
    }
    ...
    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, [GenerateEnum] ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
    {
        dest.WriteInt(myId);
        //NOT SURE HOW TO WRITE LIST -- tried the following, but don't know how to test if either is working since I am not sure how to properly read
        //dest.WriteList(myObjectList);
        //dest.WriteTypedList(myObjectList);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: `Parcelable` is ugly in Java and more so in C# since what you are "serializing" needs to be inherited from `Java.Lang.Object`, *personally* if you are trying to pass C# `POCO` vs. Xamarin.Android based `POJO`, using JSON to serialize/deserialize and passing the string is much cleaner then redo'ing your POCOs to inherit from `Java.Lang.Object` and using Java types in them to make them POJOs... otherwise here is link: http://dan.clarke.name/2012/09/implementing-iparcelable-in-mono-for-android/

Comment: So I am finding out.  I had tried going the Serializable and JSON route, but received some errors that I can't remember what they were so I decided to look into the Parcelable route.  I was able to get it to work with an object that contained another object, but haven't had as much luck when incorporating a List.  There is enough of a difference between Java and C# in this area, that I thought I would try to reach out for a C# example.